# preventing import of same stylesheet

Tags: xslt

We are using a modeling tool that generates a wsdl from the components.  The tool generates multiple wsdl files and one wsdl that imports all the wsdls it needs (some are common objects needed by several web services).  I wrote a xsl that combines all files into one but this results in some wsdls getting included more than once and sometimes as a child of itself.
This is the template that handles import elements:

```
<xsl:template match="wsdl:import">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@location)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like a way to test if a file has already been imported and if so, ignore it.  Is there a way to do this in xsl? Thanks.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a small example (source XML for 2-3 small xml documents, that can be used to demonstrate the problem). I know how to solve this problem, but want to express the answer using your own vocabulary.

Comment: Dimitre, I tried to paste code samples here but I was unable to.  Is there a way I can email you the xmls?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:key name="imports-by-location" match="wsdl:import" use="@location"/>

<xsl:template match="wsdl:import">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('imports-by-location', @location))">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@location)"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

For more information, see **muenchian method** (e.g. http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html )

Comment: This ends up ignoring all imports. I tried changing '=' to '!=' in test with same results.

Comment: What does debug say? (e.g. insert `<debug><this><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></this><first><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('imports-by-location', @location))"/></first><count><xsl:value-of select="count(key('imports-by-location', @location))"/></count></debug>` before `<xsl:if/>`)?

Comment: <debug xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <this>N1000A</this>
  <first>N1000A</first>
  <count>1</count>
</debug>

Comment: It looks like it imported only one xsl, but there should be at least 2.

Comment: If there is only a single `<debug/>` in your output, it means that `<xsl:template match="wsdl:import"/>` has only been matched once, and there is only one `<wsdl:import/>` in your input file (or you're processing other `<wsdl:import/>`s in some other template).

Comment: 3 debug statements.  Looks like the rest of my comment didn't make it.  Essentially, my error is in my key definition.  I want to exclude duplicate wsdl:import and xsd:import statements.  Your solution will work once the key definition is solved, I think.